# Firestore : How to add a field to the auto generated id in firestore when user clicks on a button in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I implemented the `FCM` notification to the user in `Cloud Functions`. By using Cloud Functions I added a document(auto generated id) into the Firestore. I need that document id to add another field as status in the same document from android app.

I had a  database path like:

```
/deyaPayUser
{authid}
/Split
{auth id }
/Received Invitation
{auto id}
  . Amount: 10
  . PhoneNumber:987654321
```

These is the data already exist . Now I need to add a field in that document. How to get the current document id of the user

```
Status : true
```

Comment: You can take a look at one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** where I have explained step by step, how to [send notification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&index=16&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee) to specific users.

Comment: @Alex why u removed the post

Comment: I am trying ur answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166811/discussion-between-lahari-areti-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: What is your difficult in getting user id from user object assuming in your android app you are using firebase authentication. Once you have user id you can add field to the document right

Comment: Not authentication id  I need auto id

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, in order to find that particular document, you need to create a `Query` based on property within that document like this:

```
Query query = yourCollectionReference.whereEqualTo("PhoneNumber", 987654321);
```

This query will find the user that has the phone number `987654321`.

Now just simply use a `get()` call, get the id and make the update:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Status", true);
yourCollectionReference.document(documentId).update(map);
```

Comment: If someone is unhappy with my answer, please provide at least the reason. Thanks! And as I understand this answer helped the OP.

Comment: @ Alex String documentId = yourCollectionReference.document().getId(); Iam getting a document but That document is not in my database. I didnot understand which document is getting

Comment: as u mentioned documentId = your collection reference.document().getId();  This line it creates a new document . But What I need is to get the document id to firestore which was created by cloud function

Comment: Just added how you can get the auto id in Node.js

Comment: @ Alex can u understand what my problem is :

Comment: first I added an auto id document into firestore by using cloud functions. After that in android whenevr user clicks on a  accept button then at the same document need to add a field as status accepted in that document  in android

Comment: So to understand better, you have a document which has an id, that you don't know which is because is created with Cloud Functions and you need to update that document with **Android** by adding a new property, is that correct?

Comment: yaa In that same document

Comment: Here we dont know the particular phonenumber to query

Comment: You need to have a common fields so you can update. If you don't have the id, because is generated by Cloud Functions, you need to query based on a property and this is how can be done. If you don't have the phone number, use another property that you know it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166887/discussion-between-lahari-areti-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: That's perfect. Keep me posted. We need to solve this.

Comment: No I did not get any solution

Comment: But it doesnot work for me because The same phonenumber has multiple documents then how can I identify which documnet currently added into the firestore

Comment: Using that query to check a particular number for existens.

Comment: I don't know which phone number to query I cannot give as an input phone number

Comment: Do u know in push notifications when the receiver gets the notifications and clicks on the accept button .whenever he clicks on accept button how to do to notify that sender your receiver has accepted ur request

Comment: Yes, use a `ValueEventListener` on that particular property. That property should be a boolean. So if  `isAccepted` to something otherwise, do something else.

Comment: can u elaborate ur answer